# Suppose $S_1,...S_n$ are injective linear maps such that $S_1S_2...S_n$ make sense. How to prove that $S_1S_2...S_n$ is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know, by definition, injectivity means this linear map maps distinct inputs into distinct outpus, and the equivalence to $nullT=｛0｝$ but I don't how to perform these on this issue, please help me with a rigorous proof, thanks!

Comment: What about induction on $n$

Comment: Prove it by induction on $n$. By the way, the question has nothing to do with linear algebra --- it's a question about one-one maps, that's all.

Comment: But I'm not familiar with this approach, would you please give me a complete example, really really appreciate it!! T_T

Comment: Dear @Gerry Myerson , maybe you are right... but I'm struggling with Linear Algebra Done Right T_T

Comment: Struggle is good. Do you know math induction?

Comment: Yes I know that, I'll give it my best try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hints:***

- Say $f, g$ are injective. Then,  $$ g \circ f(x) = g \circ f(y) \implies g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \implies f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$$
- Mathematical Induction

Comment: I roughly went through Poole's and then rushed into Axler's, but this time I treat it much more serious. I really want to learn this subject well, all by myself. Do you have another suggestion ^_^?@Ishfaaq

Comment: Oh there is no shortage of Linear Algebra books out there. I preferred Hoffman, Kunze but it is terse an not everyone's favourite. Lang is pretty good. But Sheldon Axler is not a bad book at all to start with. I suggest you stick with it.